# Pivot table in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a data frame which has data in following format:

[image]

I have to pivot up the Status column and Pivot down the states Columns to make table look like:

[image]

I am trying to do it using pd.pivot_table but unable to get the desired results.
Here is what I am trying:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(data = covid19_df_latest, index = ['Date', 'Delhi', 'Maharashtra', 'Haryana'], values = ['Status'], aggfunc = np.max)
print(table)
```

I am getting error "No numeric types to aggregate", Please suggest

Comment: Hello, please could you provide us with some more information? I’m guessing the data is stored as strings.

Comment: what is `print (covid19_df_latest.dtypes)` ?

Comment: @FChm Please let me know what additional information is required. I have shared the format of source file and what final format is required. Please let me know what additional information is required

Comment: @jezrael  Date and status are objects, rest are integer. does it answer your query? Apologies if I got it incorrect

Comment: @Vaibhav - It is correct. Can you post input data like text? Because data copy from pictures is not easy. thanks.

Comment: @jezrael Here you go, All columns after Status represent States
Date         Status         DL   MH   HR  GA
14-Mar-20 Confirmed 81 0 1 0
14-Mar-20 Recovered 9 0 0 0
14-Mar-20 Deceased 2 0 0 0
15-Mar-20 Confirmed 27 0 0 0
15-Mar-20 Recovered 4 0 0 0
15-Mar-20 Deceased 0 0 0 0
16-Mar-20 Confirmed 15 0 0 0
16-Mar-20 Recovered 1 0 0 0
16-Mar-20 Deceased 0 0 0 0
17-Mar-20 Confirmed 11 0 0 0
17-Mar-20 Recovered 1 0 0 0
17-Mar-20 Deceased 1 0 0 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df= (covid19_df_latest.melt(['Date','Status'], var_name='State')
                      .pivot_table(index=['Date','State'],
                                   columns='Status', 
                                   values='value', 
                                   aggfunc='max')
                      .reset_index()
                      .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
       Date        State  Deceased  Identified  Recovered
0  14/05/20        Delhi      1200       10000       2000
1  14/05/20      Haryana      1000       20000        800
2  14/05/20  Maharashtra      1000       15000       3700
```

**Details**: Solution first unpivot Dataframe by `melt`:

```
print (covid19_df_latest.melt(['Date','Status'], var_name='State'))
       Date      Status        State  value
0  14/05/20  Identified        Delhi  10000
1  14/05/20   Recovered        Delhi   2000
2  14/05/20    Deceased        Delhi   1200
3  14/05/20  Identified  Maharashtra  15000
4  14/05/20   Recovered  Maharashtra   3700
5  14/05/20    Deceased  Maharashtra   1000
6  14/05/20  Identified      Haryana  20000
7  14/05/20   Recovered      Haryana    800
8  14/05/20    Deceased      Haryana   1000
```

and then pivoting with `max` aggregate function.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me. I am new to Python and Pandas. Do you mind providing some details about this works also?